# How to dynamically assign an order value to a Google Ads conversion tracking script in WHMCS

Tags: google-ads, conversions, whmcs

My online store uses WHMCS.

I have the Google Analytics WHMCS app installed and configured.

I'm setting up a Google Ads campaign to send clicks to my store, and during Google Ads conversion setup, they've given me the following code to track conversions on my WHMCS site.

```
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-xxx/xxx',
      'value': 10.0,
      'currency': 'AUD',
      'transaction_id': ''
  });
</script>
```

I've added this to `templates/orderforms/standard_cart/complete.tpl`

During the Google Ads conversion setup, they asked for a default conversion value which I set to AU$10.

How do I dynamically set the value assigned to the Google Ads conversion based on the order that has just been made on the order-complete page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `{$amount}`, a WHMCS template variable, for the `value`, so it gets replaced with the amount before the page is sent to their browser.

```
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-xxx/xxx',
      'value': {$amount},
      'currency': 'AUD',
      'transaction_id': ''
  });
</script>
```